Ubuntu 22.04 Freezing
Ubuntu 22.04 keeps freezing very randomly.
The last few times it has frozen:

Warthunder after 2 hours of gameplay
Youtube after 5 minutes
Home screen after 13 hours (Over night download, Only froze once i closed Steam)

journalctl Brings back no errors, Temps are nice and cool at 50c-60c. The lockup happens slowly, frame rate drops, audio crackles then mouse stops and everything stops.
The only way around it, is a hard reset.
Fixes i have tried:

Reinstall Ubuntu 22.04
Install Ubuntu 24.04
Downgraded GPU Drivers to 490 or 545
Tested with another hard-drive
Tested with different ram

Specs:

Intel i3 12100F
MSI GT1030 2gb ddr4
Corsair 8gb ddr4 ram
WD Blue 2TB HDD
Motherboard MSI Pro 610M-G
600w EVGA PSU

What should I check to determine the cause?
